# Symfony2 concept for non-singleton objects

Tags: php, symfony, singleton

I just read this article about the [Symfony2 container concept](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html). I got the impression that every class which is instantiated through a container is a singleton object, means that it is only instantiated once and reused all the time. The example in the stated article referers to a class which serves to send emails. In this case the singleton approach might make sense.

My question is: Is there a best practice for dealing and organizing "normal" (non-singelton) objects in Symfony2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symfony has you covered.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html

Set scope: prototype when you define you service and you will get a different instance each time you get it.

I suspect that you will discover that "normal" for services is the singleton pattern.

Comment: Yes, a service in the sense of Symfony seems to be a singleton by definition. Thanks for the hint with the scope.

Answer (score 1):

If you define your service and make it accessible via container, you can also define [a factory service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/factories.html), that lets you control the creation of such objects. Using this method you can also pass whatever parameters to the constructed object, and instantiate as many objects as you desire.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for something like that. But I wonder where is the advantage over just instantiating an object in the normal Php way? In case of service container I have additional method calls which is bad for performance especially when I for example have several thousand product-objets...

Comment: I guess it's all about philosophy of OOP. Scopes, objects and design patterns. The best way preformance-wise will not be the most usable in the sense of objective paradigms. So container is all about having correct scopes.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, all classes in service container are singleton.
I don't think there is a best practice to handle normal object. But if you want to have the same instance without dealing the instantiation, you can create a service which will be a factory design pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Divi. So there is not even a suggested directory to put such classes?

Comment: The best practice is to put your class in the directory named with the name of their main job.
For example, if you create a "NewsParser", you can create a directory named "News" or "Parser", if they are many parsers on your app.
Models (or Entities) must be created in Entity folder (for Doctrine)  or Model folder (for Propel).